# I am getting error while converting yarn berry + nextjs project to standalone

Tags: docker, next.js, yarnpkg

I am using yarn berry on next.js.
and i need to reduce docker image size for this build,
so i converted to standalone build on next.js.

this is my Dockerfile.

```
FROM node:16-alpine as builder

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json ./
COPY yarn.lock ./
COPY .pnp.cjs ./
COPY .pnp.loader.mjs ./
COPY .yarnrc.yml ./
COPY .yarn .yarn
RUN yarn install --immutable

COPY . .

ARG GITHUB_SHA=0
RUN yarn build

FROM node:16-alpine AS runner

WORKDIR /app

RUN addgroup --system --gid 1001 nodejs
RUN adduser --system --uid 1001 nextjs
USER nextjs

COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public

COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/standalone ./
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/static ./.next/static

ENV NODE_ENV='production'
CMD node server.js
```

it can build to command `docker build -t standalone .`
then i can get the output image.

when i run this docker image with command `docker run -d -p3000:3000 standalone`.

I'm getting this error.

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:988
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'next/dist/server/next-server'
Require stack:
- /app/server.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:985:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:833:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1057:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/app/server.js:4:20)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1155:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1209:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1033:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:868:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ '/app/server.js' ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`CMD ["node", "-r", "./.pnp.cjs", "server.js"]`

https://yarnpkg.com/features/pnp#initializing-pnp